# Ruby: Error: Cannot locate this method: String.

Tags: ruby, pry

Any idea why certain documentation does not work when using `show-doc` in `pry`? E.g. see `show-doc` with `String` and `Array` compared to `Set` here:

```
show-doc Set

From: /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb @ line 3:
Class name: Set
Number of lines: 57

--
set.rb - defines the Set class
++
Copyright (c) 2002-2008 Akinori MUSHA <knu@iDaemons.org>

Documentation by Akinori MUSHA and Gavin Sinclair.

All rights reserved.  You can redistribute and/or modify it under the same
terms as Ruby.

  $Id: set.rb 37839 2012-11-24 18:51:45Z knu $

== Overview

This library provides the Set class, which deals with a collection

show-doc String
Error: Cannot locate this method: String.
[7] pry(main)> show-doc Array
Error: Cannot locate this method: Array.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try installing pry-doc gem:

```
gem install pry-doc
```

OR

as per @JayKilleen

> if you are using pry in your rails environment you can also try
>   installing jazz_hands instead github.com/nixme/jazz_hands which brings
>   pry and other gem functionality into rails console.

Comment: That's handy. E.g. show-doc String
From: object.c (C Method).

Comment: I have installed pry-doc and still have this issue. Just trying to follow along with Josh Cheek's introductory screencast and can't get past the first 'show-doc s.each_line' http://vimeo.com/26391171

Comment: I have fixed this by installing jazz_hands in my rails app instead https://github.com/nixme/jazz_hands which brings pry and other gem functionality into rails console

Answer (score 1):

String and Array aren't methods, they're classes. That's probably why it's giving you that error there.

Comment: Set is a class too but I'm getting documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`String` and `Array` are built-in classes written in C, and you do not have the documentation for them unless you installed them. `Set` is written in Ruby, and you probably have the documentation as part of the library.